# Silex optional locale route

Tags: locale, twig, silex

I might be approaching this the wrong way so I am open to alternatives.

I would simply like to match the following sample urls using a single route:

```
/

/welcome
/en/welcome
/fr/welcome

/my/arbitrarily/deep/path
/en/my/arbitrarily/deep/path
/fr/my/arbitrarily/deep/path
```

etc

Here is what I have so far:

```
$app->get('/{_locale}{path}', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $path = $request->attributes->get('path');
    // do stuff with path here
})
->value('_locale', 'en')
->assert('_locale','^(en|fr)?$')
->value('path', 'index')
->assert('path', '.*')
->bind('*');
```

Now this seems to work as expected, but when I try to use the twig path() or url() it fails to build the correct url, for example:#

on /foo (no locale specified on the url so defaults to en):

```
{{ path('*', {path:'foo/bar'}) }}
```

will result correctly in

```
foo/bar
```

on /fr/foo, the same call:

```
{{ path('*', {path:'foo/bar'}) }}
```

results in

```
frfoo/bar
```

This is because of the missing / between {_locale} and {path}, but by changing the route to:

```
/{_locale}/{path}
```

It stops matching /foo and only matches either /en/foo, /fr/foo or //foo.

I'm not sure where to go from here :s

I didn't want to use multiple routes (maybe one with and without a {_locale}) because I'm not sure how that works with the path() function, I basically want the result of path() to include the current locale in the url if it's not 'en' (I think is what I'm getting at).

Can anyone help me with this?

Cheers

Toby

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare a route for `/{_locale}/{path}` and `/{path}`.

As for path() , since you defined a default _locale value for the first route , there should not be any issues in your views.

Comment: This has partially resolved the issue, I added a new route /{path} with no binding so the path() function always uses the /{_locale}/{path} route for url generation.  The only problem with this is that because it's using the magic _locale, when the url is generated with path() it always includes 'en' (i.e. I go to /foo and all links on the page are /en/foo/bar).  Given I'm using _locale for Translation it looks like I might need maybe a Twig helper function to handle this conditional 'en' rather than using path().

Comment: I'm a programmer, I'm lazy. Don't tell me I have to do redundant work: automating things is what we do. This problem has been solved for Symfony2, I don't see why it couldn't be done for Silex too.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper then just answer the question or beat it.I did , you did not.